# jQuery - Having a problem with $(this).find(".event_recur").html()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying get the html within .event_recur.

```
$(".entry").each(function(){
alert($(this).find(".event_recur").html());
});


<div class="entry">
<p class="event_title">June 21st Event - eat</p>

<p class="event_start_date">1277160289</p>
<p class="event_end_date">1277505889</p>
<p class="event_body"><p>June 21-25th
</p></p>
<p class="event_recur"><p>No
</p></p>
<p class="event_body"><p>June 21-25th
</p></p>

<p class="event_location"><p>Pac Sun
</p></p>
<p class="event_categories">
Eat
</p>

</div>
```

I get nothing when I do:

```
$(".entry").each(function(){
    alert($(this).find(".event_recur").html();
});
```

I was expecting:

```
<p>No
    </p>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: All of this code is in doc ready. If I alert .event_start_date, I get back the value in the html. However it seems since .event_recur has a p tag it doesn't work :/

Comment: Please see my answer. There is no information in that p tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your function like so:

```
$(function () {
  $(".entry").each(function(){
    alert($(this).find(".event_recur").html());
  });
});
```

That will delay execution until after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Hey gddc, I do have this all within $(document).ready(function() {}); If I alert .event_start_date, I get back the value in the html. However it seems since .event_recurring has a p tag it doesn't work :/

Comment: The presence of a `<p>` tag should not affect jQuery's html() function.  In your original post there is a typo in your alert (missing a final closing paren), but if that's in your actual document it should raise an error in a utility like FireBug if you're using anything to track that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an document ready closure; i.e. change the invocation to:

```
$(function(){
  $(".entry").each(function(){
    alert($(this).find(".event_recur").html());
  });
});
```

(FYI, `$(function(){});` is an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){});`)

Comment: Sorry I should of posted. I do have all of this in $(document).ready(function() {code here});

Answer (score 1):

`No` is not in any paragraph tag right now. It's outside your desired `<p class="event_recur">`.

Comment: The doc ready thing the other answers give is also true. Two issues here.

Comment: <p class="event_recur"><p>No 
</p></p> ?

Comment: oh. ha. reading is fun! earlier it looks like <p class="event_recur"></p>No<p><p>, but I must have read it wrong.

Comment: With HTML5 doctype it would strip the nested paragraph tag out when getting the html with .html(). This is why it would come back blank.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like with HTML5 Doctype: nesting P tags was causing the issue with the selector. I'm not sure if why exactly but I turned .event-recur into a div and it output the html fine! YES!

Note to self: don't nest p tags with HTML5 doctype. I'm not positive its the doctype but maybe someone else can clarify.